# Porting form_for erb tag from Rails2 to Rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm trying to port a Rails2 app to a Rails4 app(!). I am not keeping a separate branch for the port, but instead delimiting Rails4 specific API with an 'if' clause.

```
if Rails::VERSION::STRING < "4"
    # rails2 specific api call
else
    # rails4 specific api call
end
```

So far, this works really well for controllers and models. However, I'm having an issue with `erb` for Rails2.

```
<% if Rails::VERSION::STRING < "4" %>
    <% form_for(...) do |f| %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= form_for(...) do |f| %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It fails since in Rails2, `erb` also evaluates the `else` clause and fails to render `<%= form_for(...) do |f| %>` because in Rails 2, the object returned by `form_for` has no `.to_s` method.

Do you guys know any tips to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting Rails 4 code into a block. Define *rails4_stuff* somewhere in a helper:

```
# application_helper.rb

def rails4_stuff
 yield if Rails::VERSION::STRING < "4"
end
```

And then in ERB:

```
<% rails4_stuff do %>
 <% form_for(...) do |f| %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```